# Calendar view doesn't display node titles upon first view, but will after Prev/Next are pressed

Tags: views, datetime

Our calendar is doing some strange stuff. At first, all of the node title are missing.

[image]

But by pressing Prev/Next, they then appear

[image]

I can't think of what might be causing this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you turn AJAX off? If that fix things, then check in your JavaScript Console for any errors.

Comment: @QuentinCampbell: I found the culprit, but up-voted your comment for a great suggestion! Yes, sometimes there are some underlying JS issues that, until you open the console, you'll never see. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did a comparison between our development server and production server via `drush pml | grep Enabled | grep -i views` on each server. I noticed that for some reason I left [views_rss](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rss) enabled on production but not development. After `drush dis -y views_rss` and `drush cc all && drush cron`, things appeared as normal.